# "group_by" to csv format in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Here is my CSV :-

[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdUn9.png)

But when I am trying to convert this df to csv format by using `g.to_csv('path_to_csv')` It show's me like this :-

```
S_Name      Fruit

  A         Apple
  A         Apple
  A         Apple
  B         Banana
  B         Banana
  C         Chiku
```

I want Actual Output in **csv** like this:-

```
S_Name      Fruit

  A         Apple
            Apple
            Apple
  B         Banana
            Banana
  C         Chiku
```

Can anyone help me in this , where is my mistake ?

Thank You !

Comment: @Datanovice I edit my question

Comment: check answer : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your df is already with a reset index but use this if not the case

```
g.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

what we need to do is fill the whitespace of the repeated occurrences of the `S_Name` column

we can use a combination of `shift` and `.ne()` to get these occurance and pass the indices to a list.

```
idx = g[g['S_Name'].ne(g['S_Name'].shift())].index.tolist()

print(idx)
[0, 2, 4]
```

we then use `isin` to get the inverse of these and use `.loc` to assign whitespace values to your column spaces

```
g.loc[~g.index.isin(idx),'S_Name'] = ' '
print(g)
   S_Name   Fruit
0      A   Apple
1          Apple
2          Apple
3      B  Banana
4         Banana
5      C   Chiku
```

then you can just output to your csv

`g.to_csv('filename.csv',index=False)`

Comment: @Learner then you can just output to csv, it works on my machine.